# How do you apply addon inputs to a GeoNodes modifier?

Tags: scripting, geometry-nodes, add-on

I know that the group input of geometry nodes can be used to input values from the modifier panel. I would like to be able to do the same thing from an addon in the 3D viewport. I already know how to create an addon, but how do I capture those values and input them into the GeoNodes modifier panel?